# Add target to anchor tags with jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have an html snippet:

```
<div class="wc-social-login form-row-wide">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/wc-api/auth/twitter/? return=http://www.example.com" class="button-social-login button-social- login-twitter"><span class="si si-twitter"></span>Connect with  Twitter</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com/wc-api/auth/facebook/?return=http://www.example.com" class="button-social-login button-social-login-facebook"><span class="si si-facebook"></span>Connect with  Facebook</a>
</div>
```

I need to add a target element to the anchor tags, this is inside wordpress.

I tried this with jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.wc-social-login form-row-wide a').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
    });
});
```

Any inputs on how to add a target attribute to both the tags inside the div will be very helpful.

Comment: Need to add teh target attribute dynamically on page load.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `each()`. Also your selector is wrong use `.wc-social-login.form-row-wide` instead of `.wc-social-login form-row-wide` like following.

```
$('.wc-social-login.form-row-wide a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: Yes Azim. It seems there is some other issue with the plugin I am using, the code snipped you suggested works in jsfiddle also, Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: I am getting an error with my plugin, have posted a question here

Comment: Please check if you can suggest what could be causing the issue.